# Iterate through an object HTML TableRowElement to get the innerText of one of its children

Tags: vba, excel

I have written the following script that, from this [webpage](http://www.investing.com/indices/world-indices), should be able to extract the values contained into the table field "Chg. %".

```
Sub Test()

Dim getIE As Object, appIE As Object, indexValues As Object
Set getIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
Set appIE = getIE

With appIE
.Navigate "http://www.investing.com/indices/world-indices"
.Visible = True
End With

Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()) + 10)

Set indexValues = appIE.document.getElementById("pair_13376")

End Sub
```

The variable `indexValues` is a `[object HTMLTableRowElement]`; I guess, according to the structure of the webpage, it is containing the value "-0.13%" that I need in the 8th `td.innerText`.

[image]

How can I extract this value? I have tried something like:

```
i = 0
For Each td In indexValues
    i = i + 1
    If i = 8 Then
        myValue = td.innerText
    End If
Next
```

However, this method fails because the object `indexValues` is not an iterable list of objects. Can anyone help please? 
**NOTE**: the index I'm referring to is the very first one of the webpage I've posted, i.e. "Merval"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line will give you what you want.  Change the index number if you want a different value on that row

```
     myValue = appIE.Document.getElementById("pair_13376").getElementsByTagName("td")(7).innertext
```

Comment: Great! The question is definitely solved in a very elegant way. The funny thing is that I had tried the `getElementsByTagName` call but the return was not an iterable list at first run :/ thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

**Run this code .. Is this what you wanted .. let me know if you need more help :)** **Tested**

```
    Sub Test()

Dim getIE As Object, appIE As Object, indexValues As Object
Set getIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
Set appIE = getIE

With appIE
.Navigate "http://www.investing.com/indices/world-indices"
.Visible = True
End With

Application.Wait TimeSerial(Hour(Now()), Minute(Now()), Second(Now()) + 10)

 For Each tbl In getIE.document.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
    '    tabno = tabno + 1
     '   If tabno <> 5 Then GoTo NxtTbl
            For Each rw In tbl.Rows
                nextrow = nextrow + 1
                Set Rng = Range("A" & nextrow)
                Cofs = 0
                I = 0
                For Each Cl In rw.Cells
                    I = I + 1
                    If I = Int(I / 3) * 3 Then GoTo NxtCl
                        Rng.Offset(, Cofs).Value = Cl.outerText
                        Cofs = Cofs + 1
NxtCl:
                 Next Cl
             Next rw
NxtTbl:
      Next tbl

      Range("C:E").Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Sathish. This code is getting the value through XMLHTTP request, while I'd need the program to keep on getting the values by creating and using an Internet Explorer instance. 
What I can't figure out is just the right way to iterate through the children of the HTMLTableRowDocument: technically, my object `indexValues` should be your `rw`; but so why, for example, the attribute `indexValues.Cells` is not iterable? P.s. I was anyway looking for a more "silent" solution rather than printing out all the innerText of the webpage into a range of cells :/